# counting question - set

Tags: combinatorics

In the card game Set, each card features a number of shapes, with four attributes:

Number: The number of shapes is 1, 2, or 3.

Color: Each shape is red, purple, or green.

Shape: Each shape is oval, diamond, or squiggle.

Shading: Each shape is hollow, shaded, or solid.

There is exactly one card for each possible combination of attributes.

In the game, several of the cards are dealt out, and the goal is to find a set. A set is formed by three cards, where for each attribute, either all three cards are the same, or all three cards are different.

---

(a) Find the number of sets where all three cards are the same for exactly $2$ attributes.

(b) Find the number of sets where all three cards are the same for exactly $3$ attributes.

I'm not that sure how to find the answer to the question. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: To get answer in MSE, you should show your work